# Elastic Search Date Range Filter Not Working

Tags: date, elasticsearch, filter, range, range-query

### Context

I have an index with a field called "date" which contains dates. I need an elasticsearch query that returns records where date is greater than a specific date value.

### Issue

Running the following query with range filter returns does not work.  Records with earlier dates are returned in the result set.

```
{
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "date": {
            "gt": "2014-02-23T00:00:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Questions

- What is the correct query to pull data where date is greater than a
  specific value?
- If my query is syntactically correct, is there
  something else I can go check (e.g. datatype of field is actually
  date)?
- How should I go about root causing this?
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

In lieu of implementing mapping, I came up with a partial solution.  I used Chrome to analyze some of the Kibana traffic.  I noticed Kibana is passing date filters as int values.  So, I converted the dates to ints using Unix timestamp conversion and things are working now. 
(Reference http://www.epochconverter.com/)

### What about mapping?

I looked at the mappings earlier.  On my index they don't exist.  I seem to recall reading that mappings will be inferred for known types that have strong consistency.
My date data is consistent:
- no nulls
- dates are getting flipped from SQL, to C#, to Elastic

I guess I could implement a mapping, but I'm going with the Epoch conversion for now until I have a true need to map this for some other compelling reason.

Answer (score 0):

- Your query is syntactically correct.
- Use `get mapping` API to see the document mapping:

  `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_mapping/tweet'`
- It's hard to say where goes wrong. Probably the mapping of `date` field is not date type actually.